# If $x \geq \min\{y,w\}$ then $x \leq y+w$?

Tags: inequality

If $x \geq \min\{y,w\}$ then $x \leq y+w$.

This is kind intuitive,very trivial. Or not? It's like triangular inequality, isn't it?

Comment: $x \leq y+x$ is just $0 \leq y$, no?

Comment: Now I edited...it´s $x\leq y+w$.My bad.

Comment: @MeAndMath It is still false as stated. See sebigu's example below.

Comment: Every $x$ sufficiently big will disprove your conjecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong. Take $y,w=1$ and $x=3$.

Comment: Yes,yes,yes.If you considerate $y,w$ to be equal it´s wrong.Right.I forgot that possibility...what if $y\neq w$ ?

Comment: Then take $y=0, w=1$ and $x=2$.

Comment: Take $y=2,w=3$ and $x=6$.

Comment: GREAT!THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: No problem. Please mark this questing as solved.

Comment: Of course!It's done!